# EnumDropDownListFor Change ajax call action and the selected value assign to one field of database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to update `VazList` in my database for the record that it's `enumdropdownlistfor` item has been changed. I want that the selected value be  assigned to `VazList` of that record.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "My", FormMethod.Post)) { 
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NationalIdNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CellPhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VahedList)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VazList)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NationalIdNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CellPhoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VahedList)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem=>item.VazList)
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="ثبت">
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
</body>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#item_VazList").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Indexa", "My")",
        datatype: "text",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Successful Process");
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
        }
    });
});
```

And my Action Conroller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Indexa(ViewModelPerson model, int? id)
 {
     DataBaseContext db=new DataBaseContext();
     EfPerson efp = db.People.Find(id);

     efp.VazList = model.VazList;
     db.People.Attach(efp);
     db.Entry(efp).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();

     // other changed properties

     return RedirectToAction("Sabt");
 }
```

I need that `VazList` be updated for the selected item.
Sorry if my english is not ok.
Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `item` has an `ID` property, update the line to:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem=>item.VazList, new { data_id = item.ID })
```

This will add a data parameter to the HTML like `<select data-id="id" >` (assuming you are using MVC 3+).

Then update the ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Indexa", "My")",
    datatype: "text",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : $(this).data("id") }, //<--new part, get the id 
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Successful Process");
    },
    error: function () {
        $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank u Jwatts. Is my ActionResult ok? my VazList still doesn't change in my DataBase!